# Spring Security 5.7: Equivalent of 'disableDefaults' from WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter for configuring HttpSecurity

Tags: spring-security

Since Spring Security 5.7 `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was deprecated and it is now recommended  to move towards a component-based security configuration (https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter).

Before my configuration looked somewhat similar to this:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public SecurityConfiguration() {
      // disables the defaults
      super(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            ...;
    }
}
```

The new recommended way would be something like:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            ...;
    }

}
```

I have done a lot of reading migration articles, docs and the code, but so far I am missing the equivalent of the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter#disableDefaults` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there is no such configuration. But there is an open ticket in the Spring Security repo (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/11633), which addresses this topic.